# Make sure each JAR sees its own classpath resources first

Tags: java, jar, classpath

Suppose I have 2 jars on classpath

JAR1:

```
Class1.class
resource.xml
```

JAR2:

```
Class2.class
resource.xml
```

The classes Class1 and Class2 use the classpath resource (each JAR provides its own resource.xml and wants to read it).

In my application I use both jars and when Class1 or Class2 loads, the resource.xml being loaded is random (one of the two).

Is it possible for Class1 to always load its resource.xml and Class2 its own?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is impossible to do exactly what you want.

---

Lets start with some facts about how classloaders and resource loading work

1. When you call `Class.getResource()` it turns into a call to `Class.getClassloader().getResource()`.
2. Each class has exactly one classloader.
3. Each classloader has exactly one parent classloader.
4. The way that classloaders are constructed ensures that the classloaders form a strict tree, with the so-called bootstrap classloader at the root of the tree.
5. A classloader may use one of two strategies for finding stuff:

   - ask the parent classloader first, and then check this classloader's resources,
   - check this classloader's resources first, and then ask the parent classloader.

Now, for the sake of argument, lets consider this example:

```
JAR1:

Class1.class
resource.xml
resource1.xml

JAR2:

Class2.class
resource.xml
resource2.xml
```

So lets consider how we might put this together:

- If JAR1 and JAR2 have the same classloader, then that classloader has no way of knowing which JAR should be searched first.  The `getResource()` call on the classloader doesn't know what the original class was.
- Suppose JAR1 and JAR2 have different classloaders:

  - If JAR2's classloader was the parent of JAR1's, then it can delegate to JAR2, but JAR2's classloader cannot delegate to JAR1.  If we called `Class2.class.getResource("resource1.xml")`, Class2's classloader wouldn't be able to delegate to the classloader that knows about "resource1.xml" and the load would fail.
  - If you flip it around and made JAR1's classloader the parent of JAR2's, then we'd find that `Class1.class.getResource("resource2.xml")`, would fail.
- Suppose that we created 2 classloaders that BOTH knew about JAR1 and JAR2, and neither delegated to the other.  The first classloader could look for resources in JAR1 and then JAR2 and then the parent, the second classloader could look in JAR2, JAR1, parent.

  OK so far.  But what about class loading?  Here we have to be **really careful**.  We cannot allow a situation where Class1.class might be loaded by both classloaders.  Because if that happens, you end up with two loaded types with the same fully qualified name and different class loaders.  But the Java type system says that gives us two *different* types ... and that is liable to lead to unexpected `ClassCastExceptions`.  So we have to ensure that the two respective classloaders **do not** both load the same class.

  But that leads to another problem.  If the first classloader is asked to find a class that only the other classloader can load, then it can't delegate to it ... and the end result will be that that you will get a "class not found" error or exception.

---

In summary, I think I have covered all of the plausible classloader structures ... and none of them work for the example I proposed.

It might be possible to "break the rules" and set up an *effectively* non-tree structured classloader delegation network; e.g. by using a back door to tell two classloaders about each other.  However, there is a risk that you'd end up with a delegation loop ... which would lead to "infinite" recursion.  And even if this were to work it there are other potential risks; e.g. to the Java sandbox security model which also relies on the workings of classloaders.

Don't go there.  Find another way to do this; e.g. use different names for the two versions of "resource.xml".

Comment: Yeah, I didnt like the idea in the  first place, but I was asked if this would be possible; One more thing though - what if the app (user of jar1 and jar2) had its own class loader (CL) and used a separate CL for jar1 and separate for jar2? both of those CLs could be w/o parent CL or with JDK CL as parent. Essentially I know that there won't be connections between jar1 and jar2 - they dont use each other. They simply happen to require a file with a same name.... :-(